# Storing Directory Folder Names Into Array Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, directory

I am trying to write a script that will get the names of all the folders in a specific directory and then return each as an entry in an array.  From here I was going to use each array element to run a larger loop that uses each element as a parameter for a later function call.  All of this is through powershell.

At the moment I have this code:

```
function Get-Directorys
{
    $path = gci \\QNAP\wpbackup\

    foreach ($item.name in $path)
    {
        $a = $item.name
    }
}
```

The `$path` line is correct and gets me all of the directories, however the foreach loop is the problem where it actually stores the individual chars of the first directory instead of each directories full name to each element.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's another option using a pipeline:

```
$arr = Get-ChildItem \\QNAP\wpbackup | 
       Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
       Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```

Comment: This is a more complete solution. Should be marked as answer.

Comment: this is so useful, thanks: | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}

Comment: In my case, for some reason, this joins all dir names into a single string.

Comment: Here it also seems to be a string, though I need an array. Sorry, I'm new to Powershell...

Answer (score 9):

$array = (dir *.txt).FullName

$array is now a list of paths for all text files in the directory.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, and readability:

This get all files in "somefolder" starting with 'F' to an array.

```
$FileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path '.\somefolder\' -Name 'F*' -File
```

This gets all directories of current directory:

```
$FileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path '.\' -Directory
```

Answer (score 6):

```
# initialize the items variable with the
# contents of a directory

$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp"

# enumerate the items array
foreach ($item in $items)
{
      # if the item is a directory, then process it.
      if ($item.Attributes -eq "Directory")
      {
            Write-Host $item.Name//displaying

            $array=$item.Name//storing in array

      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that your `foreach` loop variable is `$item.name`. What you want is a loop variable named `$item`, and you will access the `name` property on each one.

I.e.,

```
foreach ($item in $path)
{
    $item.name
}
```

Also take note that I've left `$item.name` unassigned. In Powershell, if the result isn't stored in a variable, piped to another command, or otherwise captured, it is included in the function's return value.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I changed to this and then assigned each return value to a var outside of the function.  From here I can now use $a[xxx] to get the value that I want.  Was unaware of your second comment about non stored values being returned that way.

Comment: Yeah. That's a little gotcha that bit me once or twice, especially since I didn't even realize I had unconsumed output at the time.