# Built-in function or Cmdlets to store all folders names in an array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have found an answer of how to store the folders names of the current folder in an array. by [@Shay Levy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9833/shay-levy) - [The Solution - Storing Directory Folder Names Into Array Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998777/storing-directory-folder-names-into-array-powershell). So is there anything built-in within PowerShell that do this process. as the variable will be used in another function later.

The solution I found:

```
$arr = Get-ChildItem \\QNAP\wpbackup | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```

Comment: Depending on your PS version, you can simply use: `$arr = Get-ChildItem \\QNAP\wpbackup -Directory -Name`. You can use the variable anywhere in that session as long as it's properly scoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use every single element in array for other scopes:

```
$wDir = '\\QNAP\wpbackup'
$arr = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Name -Path $wDir
```

---

Another solution:

```
$wDir = '\\QNAP\wpbackup'
$arr = @(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Name -Path $wDir)
```

Comment: May you explain what does ('\\QNAP\wpbackup') mean, I did not get it.

Comment: The second line worked with me when I change the variable $wDir with Dot ( . ), it has read all the folders in the current directory.

Comment: "\\QNAP\wpbackup' is the path of your working directory (you wrote it inside your code).
This code store in $arr array all directory names that is inside your path

Comment: I am sorry that I did not understood it, as I tried $wDir = '\\QNAP\wpbackup' but it stored the string "\\QNAP\wpbackup" only. So, I just have changed it to the directory path I am working on. and thank you.